# HTML input, textarea and select same width

Tags: html, input, width

I want to create a HTML form where users insert:

- A name in an input `type=text"`
- Choose a car from list using select tag
- A message in a textarea

How could I do in order to make that the input, select and textarea have the same width?

Comment: Apply css for input tag like this input[type="text"], select, textarea { width:300px; }

Comment: Everybody says that, but it should be considered margins, paddings...

Answer (score 0):

Set the css attribute width to the same value:

```
<input type="text" style="width:150px" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doen't work, all the 3 elements have different width

Answer (score 0):

You can create a css class and assign it to them:

```
<style>
.same-width{
    width:200px !important;
}
</style>
<input type="text" class="same-width">
<select class="same-width">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<textarea class="same-width"></textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doen't work, all the 3 elements have different width